# Using List Comprehension with Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get my head around list comprehensions and I can understand the basics of how they work but I get the feeling I should be able to do something with my code here that I just can't seem to get working.

Given a dictionary:

```
{2: {11},  9: {11, 8, 10}, 10: {11, 3}, 11: {7, 5},  8: {7, 3}}
```

There are a couple of snippets that I feel I should be able to reduce to fewer lines if I knew better:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    dag[k] = v
    for val in v:
        if val not in d.keys():
            dag[val] = None
```

and:

```
t = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if not v:
        t.append(k)
        d.pop(k)
```

My attempts have been variations on:

```
for [k, v in d.items() if not v]:
```

But that keeps telling me it needs an else statement and none of what I have read has helped answer how/if this is possible.

Comment: Clarity is better than briefness, so only make it shorter if it remains as clear or clearer to read. That also tends to be fast, in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, you are essentially defaulting all nodes to `None` in the `dag`. You could invert those steps and avoid testing for keys already being present altogether:

```
dag = dict.fromkeys(node for v in d.values() for node in v)
dag.update(d)
```

This creates a dictionary with all `None` values for the given keys (sourced from a generator expression), then updated to insert all known edges.

In your code you used `if val not in d.keys()`; this is functionally equivalent to `if val not in d`, but without the redundant call to `d.keys()`, which creates a new object (in Python 2, a list with all keys, making the search *extra* inefficient, in Python 3 a dictionary view is created). Always use the shorter form there.

Do be aware that the `set` objects you use as values in `d` are now shared with `dag`; any changes you make to these sets will be reflected across both dictionaries.

Creating a sequence of nodes without values would then be:

```
nodes_without_exits = [node for node, edges in d.items() if not node]
```

List comprehensions still need the *producer expression*, the part that produces the value to be inserted into the list; here that's `node`, the list is built out of the keys of the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the keys that have  falsey values the syntax is:

```
[ k for k, v in d.items() if not v]
```

That is equivalent to your last loop bar the `d.pop(k)` which I am not sure if you want. The first `k` is what we append to the list, `for k, v` is each key and value in d.items and  `if not v` means we only keep the k's that have falsey values.

If you actually want a dict without those keys and value you can use a dict comprehension where the logic is exactly the same except we are creating key/value pairings instead of just keeping just the keys in the list comprehension:

```
{ k:v for k, v in d.items() if not v}
```

As for your first code, I am not sure what you want it to do exactly but you should not be calling `.keys`, in python2 that creates a list and makes lookups `O(n)` as opposed to `0(1)` and in python 3 it is an unnecessary function call.